Help ensure English speakers can participate on meta
This site has surfaced several back-to-back meta posts written only in Italian. It's an understandable tendency, since your focus is Italian Language, but this creates some problems. The Stack Exchange Team (of which I am a member) asks that instead, you do one of two things.

Only post on meta in English or...
Post in Italian, but commit as a community to
translating every post into English in short order

The community needs to come to consensus about which approach to adopt, but it'll need to be one of the two.

Why does every meta post need to be available in English?
Our baseline goal for every SE site is...You can be reasonably sure that your question will get a good answer. 
A Q&A site isn't worth much if you can't expect that, right? Stack Exchange is English-speaking by default. We've made a couple forays into Stack Overflow in other languages and when doing so, the team carefully develops infrastructure so the site meets this basic goal.
One can't flip language support for a community on and off like a light switch without stifling lots of folks ability to understand and participate. We need everyone's contributions to uphold the first principle of "we want to all-but-guarantee good answers". So please, help us uphold these standards. 

I actually have had an impression before that all posts on Meta had to be written in English, but when I tried to find a confirmation for that in the SE help section or on meta.stackoverflow, I couldn't find any. Would you please be so kind to send me a link, if this rule is in fact written somewhere, so I could use it as a reference in the future? Thanks in advance.

Hi @I.M., thanks for asking. The Stack Exchange team has made a practice of laying down this guideline directly on site's metas, but I don't believe its documented in a more more central location yet. It probably should be. :) Give me a chance to speak with the rest of my team and we'll see about some better documentation.

thanks so much, it's exactly what I wanted! :)

Many thanks for pointing this out, Ana.
We'll kindly ask users to write on meta primarily in English. As to the already posted questions, we'll take care of adding to them an English translation asap.

Since this is an old question, and some users have expressed disconfort about communicating in English in meta, let me add a small precisation: if you don't feel confortable writing in English, please write in Italian and ping me in the Bar Sport, or flag the post as "In need of moderator intervention". I will try to add an English translation as soon as I can.
Of course other users can do the translation as well, if I happen to be busy or slow. I am just committing to do so myself if no one else does.

Visto che questa è una domanda vecchia e alcuni utenti hanno espresso disagio riguardo al comunicare in inglese in meta, fatemi aggiungere una piccola precisazione: se non vi sentite a vostro agio a scrivere in inglese, per favore scrivete in italiano e mandatemi un ping nel Bar Sport, o mandate una flag sul post come "In need of moderator intervention". Proverò ad aggiungere una traduzione in inglese appena posso.
Ovviamente anche altri utenti possono tradurre, se io sono per caso occupato o lento. Sto solo impegnandomi a farlo io se non lo fa nessuno altro.

Thanks a lot, @Denis!

In my opinion, it would be a great idea to have some posts in Meta bilingual. In fact, if you have a look to the Meta sites of other SE sites dedicated to languages, you will see lots of posts written in their own language. So, I don't understand why we shouldn't be able to use Italian in this Meta site.

@Charo Feel free to edit them, or if you prefer let me know which one you'd like translated and I'll do it as soon as I can.

Great idea to make the posts bilingual
